# RxJs emit after delay or next event on the stream

Tags: rxjs, redux-observable

I've pairs of events: `add1`/`add2`/etc and `remove1`/`remove2`/etc. I'd like the following:

- when an `add1` is emitted on the stream

  - if `DELAY` transpires with no new `add*` emissions

    - emit `remove1`
  - if `add*` is emitted

    - emit `remove1` for `add1` immediately
    - emit `remove*` for `add*` after `DELAY`

This should continue for all emissions of `add*` on the stream.

Here's a test I've written using RxJS marble testing for this case:

```
import test from 'tape'
import { set, lensPath } from 'ramda'
import { TestScheduler } from 'rxjs/testing'
import hideAfterDelay from '../another/file'
import { actionCreators } from '../another/dir'

const prefix = 'epics -> notifications'

test(`${prefix} -> hideAfterDelay`, t => {
  t.plan(1)

  const scheduler = new TestScheduler(t.deepEqual)

  const actionMap = {
    a: createAddAction('hello!'),
    b: createAddAction('goodbye!'),
    x: actionCreators.notifications.remove('hello!'),
    y: actionCreators.notifications.remove('goodbye!')
  }

  scheduler.run(({ cold, expectObservable }) => {
    const actionStream = cold('a-------a-b-a------', actionMap)
    const expected =          '-----x-----x-y----x'
    const actual = hideAfterDelay(5)(actionStream)

    expectObservable(actual).toBe(expected, actionMap)
  })
})

function createAddAction (name) {
  const action = actionCreators.notifications.add(name)
  const lens = lensPath(['payload', 'id'])

  return set(lens, name, action)
}
```

I **think** the test is representative of the behavior I described above and that I want.

How can I write this observable? I've tried using `timer` and `race` but I haven't been able to get this working...

This is an epic using [redux-observable](http://redux-observable.js.org/), btw.

Using RxJS v6

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I got a working solution using a closure and slightly modifying my test assertion.

First, the expected marble diagram should look like this

```
//   input:    a-------a-b-a------
// - expected: -----x-----x-y----x
// + expected: -----x----x-y----x
//
// Note above that the middle x and y emit at the same time as new
// `add*` actions on the source stream instead of one frame later
```

With that small change—which still feels consistent with my description in the question—I was able to get my test passing with the following:

```
import { of, timer, empty } from 'rxjs'
import { switchMap, mapTo, tap, merge } from 'rxjs/operators'
import { ofType } from '../operators'
import actionTypes from '../../actionTypes/notifications'
import { actionCreators } from '../..'

export default (delay = 3000) => actionStream => {
  let immediateRemove

  return actionStream.pipe(
    ofType(actionTypes.ADD),
    switchMap(action => {
      let obs = empty()

      if (immediateRemove) {
        obs = of(immediateRemove)
      }

      const remove = actionCreators.notifications.remove(action.payload.id)

      immediateRemove = remove

      return obs.pipe(
        merge(
          timer(delay).pipe(
            tap(() => {
              immediateRemove = null
            }),
            mapTo(remove)
          )
        )
      )
    })
  )
}
```

I've no idea if this is the best or right way to solve it, but I'm fairly certain it is **a** way.